# Put footer at bottom of either view or document, whichever is longer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a navbar-bottom on my app that I want to either be placed at the bottom of the view or the documnet, whichever is lower.  I'm getting some weird behavior and can't work it out.  Here is the code for my application.html.erb.  The idea is to make the navbar-fixed-bottom so that if the window is smaller than the document, the navbar will move down:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function (){
  var bottomPosition = $(document).height(),
      viewportHeight = $(window).height(),

    if (bottomPosition <= viewportHeight) {
      $('#bottom').attr('class', 'navbar navbar-fixed-bottom');  
    }


});
</script>
```

Here's the code for my root page (main.html.erb).  The idea here is to set the document height equal to the window height after the page loads:

```
<div class="bio" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="someURL" style="max-height:800px; float:left; padding-left:10px;"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text" style="padding-left:200px; width:350px; color:white;">
      <h4>Welcome</h4> 
        Some long paragraph      </div>
</div>

<script>
$(window).on('load', function (){
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),  
        viewHeightString = viewportHeight.toString() + 'px',
        docHeight = $(document).height();

  if (viewportHeight > docHeight){
    $('body').css({height: viewHeightString});
    console.log(viewHeightString);
    console.log(docHeight);
    }  

});
</script>
```

I've tried just using one method or the other with no luck.  Here are some pictures of what is happening.

When I load the page in a fullscreen browser window:

[image]

Example of a page that isn't root which is not placing the correctly sized navbar not at the window bottom:

[image]

Please let me know if you see what I can improve.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common CSS problem called "sticky footer" and also there are a lot of ways to solve it. With or without jQuery. You can google it and find which you'll like more.

I'm using this simple method http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: Works like a charm on a PC, but not on tablet.  I'll work it from here.